# Video driver Radeon x1200

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, video

I got the issue when I play flash games or videos it's too slow.  I reinstalled Ubuntu and it worked smooth for like 5 hours then I rebooted and it was slow again.

When I type
`sudo lshw -C display`

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
    product: RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
    vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
    physical id: 5
    bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
    version: 00
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
    resources: irq:42 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fea00000-feafffff
```

And when I type `lspci | grep VG`

```
   01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
```

I tried this page http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers but when I type `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` it brings this:
The program 'glxinfo' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
`sudo apt-get install mesa-util`

Can you help me  with this? I just want to keep watching my series on mi lap and play non-hardcore graphics games

Comment: To execute the command `glxinfo | grop OpenGL`, you must have glxinfo installed. To install glxinfo, execute `sudo apt-get install mesa-util` in a terminal.

However, I this will only show you some information, and I don't think it will solve your second problem with poor graphics performance (I still experience it, looking for a different solution).